# Objective C - Making UILabel update as user types text in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How would I make a UILabel update as a user enters text in a UITextField. In my case, I have a quadratic equation solver for the iPhone and as the user enters the values of a b & c, I want a UILabel to update with the numbers given by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then your textFieldDidChange method is just something like:

```
self.quadLabel.text = self.quadInput.text;
```